# Comparing common strings in two pandas dataframe columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas data frame as follows:

```
coname1        coname2
Apple          [Microsoft, Apple, Google]
Yahoo          [American Express, Jet Blue]
Gap Inc       [American Eagle, Walmart, Gap Inc]
```

I want to create a new column that flags whether the string in coname1 is contained in conames.  So, from the above example, the dataframe would now be:

```
coname1        coname2                               isin
Apple          [Microsoft, Apple, Google]            True
Yahoo          [American Express, Jet Blue]          False
Gap Inc       [American Eagle, Walmart, Gap Inc]     True
```

Comment: What is your question (as in a sentence with a question mark)? You state what you want only. Is there a problem achieving that. Are you looking to hire a programmer? Do you run into a problem with an erorr (if so which one). This is a site for programmers, so including some code is more or less mandatory.

Answer (score 6):

set up frame:

```
df =pd.DataFrame({'coname1':['Apple','Yahoo','Gap Inc'],
          'coname2':[['Microsoft', 'Apple', 'Google'],['American Express', 'Jet Blue'],
                     ['American Eagle', 'Walmart', 'Gap Inc']]})
```

try this:

```
df['isin'] =df.apply(lambda row: row['coname1'] in row['coname2'],axis=1)
```

Comment: This works, but is VERY slow for larger dataframes.  Using a list comprehension is far faster per the answer and my comment in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/q/43855685/6163621