# Check if string in one column is contained in string of another column in the same row

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

```
RecID| A  |B
----------------
1    |a   | abc 
2    |b   | cba 
3    |c   | bca
4    |d   | bac 
5    |e   | abc
```

I want to create another column, C, out of A and B such that for the same row, if the string in column A is contained in the string of column B, then C = True and if not then C = False.

The example output I am looking for is this:

```
RecID| A  |B    |C 
--------------------
1    |a   | abc |True
2    |b   | cba |True
3    |c   | bca |True
4    |d   | bac |False
5    |e   | abc |False
```

Is there a way to do this in pandas quickly and without using a loop?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

You need `apply` with `in`:

```
df['C'] = df.apply(lambda x: x.A in x.B, axis=1)
print (df)
   RecID  A    B      C
0      1  a  abc   True
1      2  b  cba   True
2      3  c  bca   True
3      4  d  bac  False
4      5  e  abc  False
```

Another solution with `list comprehension` is faster, but there has to be no `NaN`s:

```
df['C'] = [x[0] in x[1] for x in zip(df['A'], df['B'])]
print (df)
   RecID  A    B      C
0      1  a  abc   True
1      2  b  cba   True
2      3  c  bca   True
3      4  d  bac  False
4      5  e  abc  False
```

Comment: Wow, I wish I knew you could use apply in that way to use multiple columns for a calculation. I'm assuming this is way quicker than using data.iterrows()?

Comment: I thonk yes, it should be faster.

Comment: Timing test - I ran this on a dataframe with about 90k rows: lambda version took 9.4245 seconds, list comprehension took 0.0308 seconds.  With the caveat of no `NaN` in the series per jezrael's note.

Comment: Sorry, I get an error: `TypeError: argument of type 'float' is not iterable`, as there are `NaN`s in `df['B']`, any ideas to deal with this?

Comment: Here's a version using `apply` that will handle `NaN`s. This checks to see if `x.A` is a null, returns False if so, and then checks for `x.A` in `x.B` otherwise:

`df['C'] = df.apply(lambda x: False if pd.isnull(x.A) else x.A in x.B, axis=1)`

Answer (score 8):

If you are comparing string to string and getting the Type Error you can code this like that:

```py
df['C'] = df.apply(lambda x: str(x.A) in str(x.B), axis=1)
```

Comment: Note that if `x.B` contains the string `'nan'` you will get some false positives here.

Answer (score 7):

I could not get either answer @jezreal provided to handle None's in the first column. A slight alteration to the list comprehension is able to handle it:

```
[a in b if a is not None else False for a,b in zip(df['A'], df['B'])]
```