# Matching if value of a column in a df is one of the values of another column in the same dataframe(going row by row)

Tags: python, string, pandas, matching

df

```
col1  col2
A      a|x|y
B      a|x|y
C      c|x|z
D      e|j|y
```

My objective is to make a new column named 'status' to see if entry in col1 is one of the entry in col2 (separated by pipe). 
output should be like this

```
col1  col2     status
A      a|x|y   True
B      a|x|y   False
C      c|x|z   True
D      e|j|y   False
```

My code:

```
df["col1"]= df["col1"].str.lower()
df['status']=df['col1'].isin(df['col2'])
```

But this is giving all entry in column 'status' as False

Please help me with this, please!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43855735/9209546), you can use a list comprehension. Assumes your data is clean, e.g. no null values.

```
zipper = zip(df['col1'], df['col2'])
df['status'] = [i.casefold() in j.casefold().split('|') for i, j in zipper]

print(df)

  col1   col2 status
0    A  a|x|y   True
1    B  a|x|y  False
2    C  c|x|z   True
3    D  e|j|y  False
```

Comment: i.casefold i could not use because i am using python 2.7 so i replaced i.casefold() to i.lower() and its giving the desired output. Thanks! @jpp

Answer (score 3):

#### `get_dummies`

```
df.col2.str.get_dummies().mul(pd.get_dummies(df.col1.str.lower())).sum(1).astype(bool)

0     True
1    False
2     True
3    False
dtype: bool
```

---

```
a = pd.get_dummies(df.col1.str.lower())
b = df.col2.str.get_dummies()
status = b.mul(a).sum(1).astype(bool)
df = df.assign(status=status)

df

  col1   col2  status
0    A  a|x|y    True
1    B  a|x|y   False
2    C  c|x|z    True
3    D  e|j|y   False
```

---

#### `get_dummies` and `einsum`

```
a = pd.get_dummies(df.col1.str.lower())
b = df.col2.str.get_dummies()
a, b = a.align(b, fill_value=0)
status = np.einsum('ij,ij->i', a, b).astype(bool)

df = df.assign(status=status)
df

  col1   col2  status
0    A  a|x|y    True
1    B  a|x|y   False
2    C  c|x|z    True
3    D  e|j|y   False
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you should bring your dataframe into a format that's easier to work with first.

I suggest something like this:

```
>>> df = pd.concat([df['col1'], df['col2'].str.upper().str.split('|', expand=True)], axis=1)                                                                                                             
>>> df                                                                                                                                                                                                   
  col1  0  1  2
0    A  A  X  Y
1    B  A  X  Y
2    C  C  X  Z
3    D  E  J  Y
```

Now you can do:

```
>>> df['status'] = df.apply(lambda s: s.duplicated().any(), axis=1)                                                                                                                                     
>>> df                                                                                                                                                                                                    
  col1  0  1  2  status
0    A  A  X  Y    True
1    B  A  X  Y   False
2    C  C  X  Z    True
3    D  E  J  Y   False
```

This solution assumes that the status indicators you separate with `'|'` are unique, i.e. that you can't have something like `'x|x|x'`.

---

If you don't like the suggestion, consider:

```
>>> df['status'] = df.apply(lambda row: row[0].lower() in row[1].split('|'), axis=1)                                                                                                                     
>>> df                                                                                                                                                                                                  
   col1   col2  status
0    A  a|x|y    True
1    B  a|x|y   False
2    C  c|x|z    True
3    D  e|j|y   False
```