# Errors when looping with iterrows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with 2 columns and I want to create a 3rd column that returns True or False for each row according to if the value in column A is contained in the value in column B .

Here's my code:

```
C = []

for index, row in df.iterrows():
        if row['A'][index] in row['B'][index]:
                C[index] = True
        else:
                C[index] = False
```

I get the following errors:

```
1) TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable
2) IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

How can I solve these errors?

Comment: please provide a snippet of your dataframe. Or an example dataframe

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Pandas: Check if string in one column is contained in string of another column in the same row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43855685/python-pandas-check-if-string-in-one-column-is-contained-in-string-of-another-c)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is some values of row['A'] or row['B'] contain float values. This is why when you get that float value you can not subscript it. Otherwise it would be like [float][index] which is what giving error. Are you expecting a string value there? It could be possible not all values are having same data type in the data frame.

Secondly, the index is of the row, I don't now why are you using it like this. For more clarifications I need to take a look at that data, but what seems possible is like even if you got a string or array value for row ['A'], which could be traversed, the index is too large. For ex-

```
row['A'] = "hello"
a  = row['A'][10]
```

will give you the index error.