# Error: Series' object has no attribute 'contains'"

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I search on all columns (except the first) of my DataFrame and add a new column 'Matching_Columns' with the name of the matching column,
When I try to remove all dots before testing if my pattern is contained within a row I receive an error.

This works:

```
keyword='123456789'
f = lambda row: row.apply(str).str.contains(keyword ,na=False, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
df1 = df.iloc[:,1:].apply(f, axis=1)

df.insert(loc=1, column='Matching_Columns', value=df1.dot(df.columns[1:] + ', ').str.strip(', '))
```

This gives me an error:

```
keyword='123456789'
f = lambda row: row.apply(str).str.replace(".","").contains(keyword ,na=False, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
df1 = df.iloc[:,1:].apply(f, axis=1)

df.insert(loc=1, column='Matching_Columns', value=df1.dot(df.columns[1:] + ', ').str.strip(', '))
```

Error:

```
AttributeError: ("'Series' object has no attribute 'contains'", 'occurred at index 0')
```

I can't figure out what's wrong with this. It looks like the `str.replace(".","")` is causing the error.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It should be `str.contains` because `contains` is an accessor of `str` not `series`.

So, to explain this better, `str.replace` returns a `series` object. You have injected `contains` function to series. That's why you are getting the error `'Series' object has no attribute 'contains'`

```
f = lambda row: row.apply(str).str.replace(".","").str.contains(keyword, na=False, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
```

Comment: An additional question if that is allowed. Now I'm using a static keyword. Is it possible to use the first column as keyword and test  if my pattern is contained in one of the other columns?

Comment: @JohnDoe Use `apply`. i.e. suppose you have cols `text` and `to_find`, then use `df.apply(lambda x: x['to_find'] in x['text'], axis=1)`

Comment: Refer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43855685/python-pandas-check-if-string-in-one-column-is-contained-in-string-of-another-c

Comment: `.str` is an accessor available to Series with the `object` datatype. All of the available [accessors](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/series.html#accessors) and the dtype restrictions are in that link.

Comment: @JohnDoe Now that this question is solved, you may ask another question if you have some issues. The S.O. community will help.