# How to apply the find method to a series

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'find'  



 indexNames = newDF[newDF["Name"].find("Peanut") != -1].index

 newDF.drop(indexNames , inplace=True)
```

The newDF DataFrame is this:

```
ProductID             int64
Description          object
Name                 object
Manufacturer         object
SumOfQtyOfProduct     int64
```

Comment: *string methods in python* are accessed with the *`str` accessor in pandas*, **example -> [`series,str.find`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.find.html)**. Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56607664/error-series-object-has-no-attribute-contains/56607678

Comment: Please provide a minimal example with input and expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `.str.find` instead of `.find`:

```
indexNames = newDF[newDF["Name"].str.find("Peanut") != -1].index
```