# Check if a column contains value from other column and fill third column (True or False)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'f like to check if a column contains a value from other column and a fill third column with True or False.

df in:

```
id | name  | account
-------------------
01 | John  | AB01
02 | Emma  | AB03
03 | Alice | AB03
```

df out:

```
id | name  | account | match
----------------------------
01 | John  | AB01    | True
02 | Emma  | AB03    | False
03 | Alice | AB03    | True
```

I've tried this:

```
df['match'] = np.where(df['account'].contains(df['id']), 'True','False')
```

Error: AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'contains'

```
df['match'] = np.where(df['account'].str.contains(df['id']), 'True','False')
```

Error: TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: ```str.contains()``` takes a string variable in stead of a series. The way I know is you can use for loop to loop all the id you have... but I'm pretty sure there are other better ways to do it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For test if contains values per rows use `apply` with `in`

For boolean `True, False`:

```
df['match'] =  df.apply(lambda x: x['id'] in x['account'], axis=1)
```

For strings `'True', 'False'`:

```
df['match'] =  np.where(df.apply(lambda x: x['id'] in x['account'], axis=1), 'True','False')


print (df)
   id   name account  match
0  01   John    AB01   True
1  02   Emma    AB03  False
2  03  Alice    AB03   True
```

EDIT:

There are missing values, so possible solution is use `np.nan == np.nan` is `False`, so added `if-else` statement:

```
print (df)
   id   name account
0  01   John    AB01
1  02   Emma     NaN
2  03  Alice    AB03
```

For boolean `True, False`:

```
df['match'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['id'] in x['account'] 
                                 if x['account'] == x['account'] 
                                 else False, axis=1)
```

For strings `'True', 'False'`:

```
df['match'] = np.where(df.apply(lambda x: x['id'] in x['account'] 
                                          if x['account'] == x['account'] 
                                          else False, axis=1), 'True','False')
print (df)
   id   name account  match
0  01   John    AB01   True
1  02   Emma     NaN  False
2  03  Alice    AB03   True
```

Another idea is use custom function with `try-exception` statement:

```
def test(x):
    try:
        return x['id'] in x['account']
    except Exception:
        return False
```

For boolean `True, False`:

```
df['match'] = df.apply(test, axis=1)
```

For strings `'True', 'False'`:

```
df['match'] = np.where(df.apply(test, axis=1), 'True','False')
```

Comment: I get an error: `TypeError: ("argument of type 'float' is not iterable", 'occurred at index 776')` in my data. I changed it thisway. Not sure if it's correct `np.where(df.apply(lambda x: str(x['id']) in str(x['account']), axis=1), 'True','False')`. Is it possble to search for `1,2 & 3` instead of `01, 02, 03`

Comment: You should add this `NaN` test to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43855685/python-pandas-check-if-string-in-one-column-is-contained-in-string-of-another-c) of you so you can mark it as dupe next time

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
df['match'] = df.apply(lambda x: x.account.str.contains(str(x.id)), axis=1)
```

Comment: My bad, it's `x.id` not `df.id`!