# Pandas merge TypeError: object of type ‘NoneType’ has no len()

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of the results of an online tournament held on BO 3 system.

it look basically like this:

```
Player blue | Player red | Map 1 | Map 2 | Map 3
Player 1    | Player 2   | blue  | red   | red
Player 3    | Player 4   | blue  | blue  | N\A
Player 5    | Player 6   | blue  | red   | blue
```

And so on. Let's say it contains 3 records

What I want to achieve is

```
Player name | Won | lost | WR %
Player 1
player 2
Player 3 
Player 4 
Player 5
Player 6
```

6 records in total. I have now a df containing one column with list of 6 player, however, when I try to merge it with first df to count win and loss I'm receiving TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len().
What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

You can try these steps:

1. Convert `map` and `winner color` into two columns using [melt](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.melt.html):

```
df = df.melt(id_vars=["Player blue", "Player red"],
              var_name="Map", value_name="Winner")
print(df)
#   Player blue Player red    Map Winner
# 0    Player 1   Player 2  Map 1   blue
# 1    Player 3   Player 4  Map 1   blue
# 2    Player 5   Player 6  Map 1   blue
# 3    Player 1   Player 2  Map 2    red
# 4    Player 3   Player 4  Map 2   blue
# 5    Player 5   Player 6  Map 2    red
# 6    Player 1   Player 2  Map 3    red
# 7    Player 3   Player 4  Map 3    N\A
# 8    Player 5   Player 6  Map 3   blue
```

2. Do the same with the `Player Blue` and `Player Red` columns:

```
df = df.melt(id_vars=["Map", "Winner"],
             var_name="Color", value_name="Player")
print(df)
#       Map Winner        Color    Player
# 0   Map 1   blue  Player blue  Player 1
# 1   Map 1   blue  Player blue  Player 3
# 2   Map 1   blue  Player blue  Player 5
# 3   Map 2    red  Player blue  Player 1
# 4   Map 2   blue  Player blue  Player 3
# 5   Map 2    red  Player blue  Player 5
# 6   Map 3    red  Player blue  Player 1
# 7   Map 3    N\A  Player blue  Player 3
# 8   Map 3   blue  Player blue  Player 5
# 9   Map 1   blue   Player red  Player 2
# 10  Map 1   blue   Player red  Player 4
# 11  Map 1   blue   Player red  Player 6
# 12  Map 2    red   Player red  Player 2
# 13  Map 2   blue   Player red  Player 4
# 14  Map 2    red   Player red  Player 6
# 15  Map 3    red   Player red  Player 2
# 16  Map 3    N\A   Player red  Player 4
# 17  Map 3   blue   Player red  Player 6
```

3. Get Winners as `boolean` (source: [ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43855735/10041823))

```
df['Won'] = df.apply(lambda x: x.Winner in x.Color, axis=1)
```

4. Compute stats using [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)

```
def getStat(df):
    return pd.Series([sum(df.Won), sum(~df.Won), sum(df.Won)/df.shape[0]*100], index=["Won", "Lost", "WR (%)"])
df = df.groupby("Player").apply(getStat)
print(df)
#           Won  Lost     WR (%)
# Player
# Player 1  1.0   2.0  33.333333
# Player 2  2.0   1.0  66.666667
# Player 3  2.0   1.0  66.666667
# Player 4  0.0   3.0   0.000000
# Player 5  2.0   1.0  66.666667
# Player 6  1.0   2.0  33.333333
```

**Note**: the `NA` match is computed as a defeat for both team, feel free to remove the `NA` lines after the step 1.