# How to create a new column in pandas df, based on condition: Column A isin Column B

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, isin

In Pandas, I want to create a new column (C) in dataframe df based on condition: If column A contains column B then "OK", else "Not OK"

I did the following but it doesn't work. Any suggestions?

```
import pandas as pd

import numpy as np

df=pd.DataFrame({'A':['Mary, Tom, Steve','Mary, Kim','Petr, Steve','Petr, Mary'],
                 'B':['Kim','Kim','Kim','Mary']})

df['C']=np.where(df['A'].isin(df['B'].astype(str)), 'OK', 'Not OK')
```

I did also

```
df['C']=np.where(df['A'].isin(df['B']), 'OK', 'Not OK')
```

and in both cases the output is the same and is the df below:

[image: Output of df]

The correct output should be

[image: Correct output of df]

Thanks in advance

Comment: `df['C'] = np.where(df.apply(lambda x: x.B in x.A, axis=1), 'OK', 'Not OK')` or `df['C'] = df.apply(lambda x: 'OK' if x.B in x.A else 'Not OK', axis=1)`

Comment: `df['C'] = np.where([x[0] in x[1] for x in zip(df['B'], df['A'])], 'OK', 'Not OK')` or `df['C'] = ['OK' if x[0] in x[1] else 'Not OK' for x in zip(df['B'], df['A'])]`

Comment: Both derived from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43855735/15497888)