# Pandas dataframe: Check if regex contained in a column matches a string in another column in the same row

Tags: python, regex, pandas

Input data is a Pandas dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['strings'] = ['apple','house','hat','train','tan','note']
df['patterns'] = ['\\ba','\\ba','\\ba','n\\b','n\\b','n\\b']
df['group'] = ['1','1','1','2','2','2']

df

    strings patterns    group
0   apple   \ba         1
1   house   \ba         1
2   hat     \ba         1
3   train   n\b         2
4   tan     n\b         2
5   note    n\b         2
```

The `patterns` column contains regex. `\b` is a regex pattern that matches on word boundaries. That means `\ba` would match with 'apple' because `a` is at the beginning of the word, while it would not match 'hat' because this `a` is in the middle of the word.

**I want to use the regex in the `patterns` column to check if it matches with the `strings` column in the same row.**

Desired result:

```
    strings patterns    group
0   apple   \ba         1
3   train   n\b         2
4   tan     n\b         2
```

I got it to work below using `re.search` and a for loop that loops line by line. But this is very inefficient. I have millions of rows and this loop takes 5-10 minutes to run.

```
import re
for i in range(len(df)):
  pattern = df.at[i,"patterns"]
  test_string = df.at[i,"strings"]
  if re.search(pattern, test_string):
    df.at[i,'match'] = True
  else:
    df.at[i,'match'] = False

df.loc[df.match]
```

**Is there a way to do something like `re.search(df['patterns'], df['strings'])`?**

This question appears to be similar: [Python Pandas: Check if string in one column is contained in string of another column in the same row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43855685/python-pandas-check-if-string-in-one-column-is-contained-in-string-of-another-c)

However, the question and answers in the above link are not using regex to match, and I need to use regex to specify word boundaries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use a pandas builtin method directly. You will need to `apply` a `re.search` per row:

```
import re

mask = df.apply(lambda r: bool(re.search(r['patterns'], r['strings'])), axis=1)
df2 = df[mask]
```

or using a (**faster**) list comprehension:

```
mask = [bool(re.search(p,s)) for p,s in zip(df['patterns'], df['strings'])]
```

output:

```
  strings patterns group
0   apple      \ba     1
3   train      n\b     2
4     tan      n\b     2
```

Answer (score 1):

Compiling a regex is costly. In your example, you only have few regexes, so I would try to cache the compiled regex:

```
cache = dict()
def check(pattern, string):
    try:
        x = cache[pattern]
    except KeyError:
        x = re.compile(pattern)
        cache[pattern] = x
    return x.search(string)
mask = [bool(check(p, s)) for p, s in zip(df['patterns'], df['strings'])]
print(df.loc[mask])
```

For your tiny dataframe it is slighly longer than @mozway's solution. But if I replicate it up to 60000 line, it saves up to 30% of execution time.

Comment: if you have many repeated patterns, one way to go IMO might be to use a `groupby` on the pattern with a fixed regex per group. You can also use [`functools.cache`/`lru_cache`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html) to perform caching ;)