# Extract rows Pandas If the value of column is contained in another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataset (see figure)
[image: dataframe]

I need to extract all rows from the Results data frame such that Results['Class'] is in Results[Path_x']

(In the specific case, it should only return me the second-to-last line because Results['Class'] is totally contained in Results['Path_x'] in the penultimate case)

I tried the following line of code:

```
results=results[results['Class'].isin(results['Path_x'])]
```

However, that line always generates an empty data frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
mask = results.apply(lambda x: ['Class'] in results['Path_x'], axis=1)
results= results.loc[mask, :]
```

See this question: [Python Pandas: Check if string in one column is contained in string of another column in the same row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43855685/python-pandas-check-if-string-in-one-column-is-contained-in-string-of-another-c)